# What are labels in the context of code repositories?

Tags: version-control, label, version

In the context of version control, are labels different from globally unique revision numbers?  I've read about labels for source code management solutions.  Some repositories make the user enter a descriptive comment.  Some repositories don't have globally unique revision numbers.

Is there a consensus on what a *label* is for version control systems?  Or is the definition ambiguous for this context?  It seems like some authors use "label" as a synonym for a decimal number whereas others use "label" to mean an arbitrary, descriptive English word that some source code management systems support when code is checked in.

Comment: Is this question *specific* about CVS (which is a specific [SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCM) product)? In the general sense *a label is just a short human-readable name that represents a particular branch/change-set, such as "release-1.0"* - instead of CS#1212324123 (or whatever branch represents that release). Depending on SCM/policy a label may move, or it may be fixed to a particular branch/change-set.

Comment: Usually *each* SCM has it's own form to identify of 'branch/version' which may be a number (eg. SVN or TFS) or a hash (eg. Git or Hg) although it could be anything really - see the respective SCM documentation.

Comment: This question is not specific to CVS.

Comment: Then: "definition [is somewhat] ambiguous" depending on specific SCM context.